# Использование QString

Tags: pyqt4

Какие модули импортировать чтобы воспользоваться QString?
Так не получается:

```
import PyQt4
```

или

```
from PyQt4 import *
```

интерпретатор не видит QString

```
s = QtCore.QString('foo')
```

не компилируетя, выдает

```
'module' object has no attribute 'QString'
```

Comment: на зарубежных форумах пишут, что такая проблема только на Python-3 - в нем не обьявлен тип QString и предлагают, если все-таки необходимо его использование поместить перед этим такую конструкцию:
 QString = type("")

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> QtCore.QString("test")
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'test')
>>>
```

python 2.7 без проблем.

Comment: Да, но в Python 3.x - проблема